# "That three days ago comment" - when referring to a comment

Tags: sentence-structure, adjective-phrases

Is it correct to specify the period of a comment since its insertion when referring to it, like instead of saying:

> There is a comment that has been submitted **three days ago** in which it has gained more popularity than yours.

I would say:

> That **three days ago** comment has gained more popularity than yours.

?

And would that part (*three days ago*) function as an adjective of the noun (*comment*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to say this:

> the comment **from three days ago**
>
> the **three-day-old comment**
>
> the comment (that was) **posted three days ago**

All of these act as adjectives of one sort or another, modifying "comment".

Comment: Thank you very much, Andrew. Could you please explain why it is **day**, not **days**, in the second suggestion?

Comment: @TasneemZH  Hm.  I really don't know why.  It just always is, in this structure, e.g. *five-day-old bread* or *two-week-old news*.

Comment: @TasneemZH Note that it's quite possible to say *that three-days-ago comment*. If you use hyphens, it's clear that the phrase is acting as an adjective. you could also say *that "three days ago" comment*, where putting the phrase inside quotation marks serves the same function. Using *three-days-ago* as an adjectival phrase is unusual, but its meaning is clear—and adjectival phrases are made up like that all the time. (*"That I'd-rather-forget-about-it comment I made yesterday."*)

Comment: @JasonBassford _ Thank you for providing and sharing such useful information!